# Difference between "Notizen" and "Aufzeichnungen" to mean notes

Tags: english-to-german, difference

When I looked up English to German translation for "notes" I saw "Aufzeichnungen." But previously had seen "Notizen", when would either one of those words be more appropriate than the other to mean notes?

I think the difference might be due to the context because "notes" in English mean various things. There are musical notes, and there are notes as in what you write down. I am looking for notes as in the ones that you write down.

I was looking for the translation of "sky notes" which I thought was "Himmel Notizen", but would it actually be "Himmel Aufzeichnungen"?

Comment: What are sky notes?

Comment: No idea what "sky notes" are supposed to be, but there's a good chance you would put it as a single (compound) word in german, e.g. "Himmelsnotizen" or "Himmelsaufzeichnungen".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both *Aufzeichnungen* and *Notizen* can mean "notes" in the sense of "taking notes". (Of course, musical notes are *Noten*, and don't belong here.)

Note also (pun intended) that *Aufzeichnungen* can mean more than "notes" (for example, "live recording").

I think the difference between *Aufzeichnungen* and *Notizen* is quite subtle when both mean "notes". Personally, I feel that *Aufzeichnungen* refer to notes that have been taken and exist as some sort of collection of notes. Wikipedia says, it should be at most

- *ein schriftliches Protokoll* (written transcript/log)
- *(plur.) "Aufzeichnungen": Tagebucheintragungen* (diary entries)
- *historische Annalen* (historical annals)

but I'm not sure it's always used as strictly as that. *Notizen*, on the other hand, can be as short as they want to be and *Notizen* is the term usually used for "taking notes": *sich Notizen machen*.

*sich Aufzeichnungen (über etwas) machen* also exists and probably means something like "serious note-taking", that is to make a collection of notes (about a particular subject), which are later to be used/reviewed/made into a book/etc.

Comment: So in my example, would "Himmel Notizen" sound proper if I was talking about notes regarding the sky.

Comment: @JGallardo That also depends on the context. If it was astronomy releated (I tried searching online), "Himmelsnotizen" would be okay.

Comment: Notizen klingt für mich informeller (z.B. handschriftlich) als Aufzeichnungen (offiziell).

Comment: @Robert Ich denke, dass Aufzeichnungen auch inoffiziell und handschriftlich sein können. Z.B. "Bislang unveröffentlichte Aufzeichnungen von Erich Kästner erscheinen am 35. Mai im Südsee Verlag."